# How to align an image horizontally inside an ImageView iOS?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an image view in landscape mode. When I selects an image from gallery, that selected image can be in landscape, portrait and square. And also I transform the original image into `1280x960`. After the image selected the image should be change according to the image. Currently I got the following output. How may I centre the image inside the image view?
[image]

Comment: Did you try to add horizontally centered constraint to the uiimageview? Also you might need to change the uiimageview to be aspectFit

Comment: No that is not the problem.. This black space is the image view and after i resized the image it shows like this. How may I centre the image inside the image view

Comment: Do you have any constraint on the uiimageview? Have you tried with the aspectfit or aspectfill options?

Comment: yes. I tied with both of them. and yes I have constraints on image view

Comment: Could you please add some information about those constraints... or you could try to remove the constraints to see if the constraints are the reason for this problem